# Cargar options de una tabla en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo 2 tablas con su respectivo modelo y controlador. Una es `productos` y otra `marca`. Hice un **scaffold** para ambas. En el formulario de productos puse un `select` con la idea de que se carguen los **options** en base a los datos que hay en la tabla `marcas` (`marcas`, solo tiene `id` y `nombre`). ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails te da distintas alternativas para hacer esto.

**Nota Previa:** Por tu pregunta no es posible saber si marca es una asociación de producto. Voy asumir que este es el caso porque tendría más sentido. Si no lo es en vez de pasar el valor *id* tendrías que pasar *nombre*

**1) Usando *options_from_collection_for_select()***

Este helper the rails te permite hacer exactamente esto. Necesita un mínimo de 3 argumentos: la colección, el valor a pasar al formulario y el valor a mostrar en el formulario.

```
# Tu Vista
...
<%= f.select :marca_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Marca.all, :id, :nombre) %>
```

Más info de este método [aquí](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

**2) Usando *collection_select()***

El resultado es muy parecido al anterior. Toma los mismos argumentos.

```
# Tu Vista
...
<%= f.collection_select :marca_id, Marca.all, :id, :nombre %>
```

Más info de este helper [aquí](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

**3) Usando *pluck* para crear tu colección**

Si no queremos usar los helpers de rails podemos hacer esto. Tal como recomienda Alter Lagos, debería hacerse en un helper para no ensuciar tanto la vista (En las que debería haber la menos lógica posible).

```
#app/helpers/tu_helper.rb
...
def marcas_for_select
  Marca.all.pluck(:id, :nombre)
end

# Tu vista
...
<%= f.select :marca_id, marcas_for_select %>
```

**4) Usando *map* para crear tu colección**

Pluck es sin duda lo más eficiente cuando queremos usar para el select campos de la base de datos. Pero que pasa si queremos usar un método creado en el modelo. Por ejemplo:

```
#app/models/marca.rb
...
def nombre_con_id
  "#{self.id}-#{self.nombre}"
end
```

En ese caso *pluck* no nos sirve y usamos *map*

```
#app/helpers/tu_helper.rb
...
def marcas_con_metodo_decorado
  Marca.all.map { |m| [m.id, m.nombre_con_id]}
end

<%= f.select :marca_id, marcas_con_metodo_decorado %>
```

**Notas:**

- Para hacerlo más breve he creado la colección en la vista (Marca.all) pero no es buena práctica. Deberías crearla en el controlador y pasarla como una variable de clase.

Comment: Realizando el Helper que se describe con .pluck.
¿Cual es la forma correcta para mostrar el :nombre, pero seleccionar el :id para el formulario?
¿convertirlo a hash? def marcas_for_select Marcas.pluck(:nombre, :id).to_h
end Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En un helper pon algo como:

```
def marcas_for_select
   Marcas.pluck(:nombre, :id)
end
```

luego en tu formulario usas:

```
<%= f.select(:marca_id, marcas_for_select, { include_blank: 'Seleccionar Marca' }) %>
```